# Is there a way to print all sprite frames in my sharedSpriteFrameCache?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Is there a way to print all objects contained in my scene's sharedSpriteFrameCache in the console? Something using NSLog or CCLOG?

I have this in my scene, and want it to print the names of the frames as they appear in the plist.

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"samplesprites.plist"];
```

Normally I'd write what I've already tried here, but I haven't found anything referencing a way to access the sprite frame names, or keys, or objects, or whatever for the sharedSpriteFrameCache.

EDIT: I probably should elaborate on the fact that I do know the frame names are in the plist file, however, I'm encountering an error where the console says my frame name doesn't exist, but I know it does. I've found various work-arounds for it, but this is more of a curiosity question for the troubleshooting approach that I'm trying to use. The requested technique may not have any real use, but, can it actually be done?

Comment: I think that cocos won't give you that, but you could extract them directly from your plist. Anyway I am not sure if there is a better answer.
Good luck!

Edit: I have looked the code, and there is a dictionary called spriteFrames_ which contain all the frames info. Its keys are the image names, so you could hack the class to be able to access that dictionary and then iterate its keys.

Comment: I'll take a look into the spriteFrames_ dict and see what I can pull from it, if anything. Thanks for the find! I'll report back if I can get it to yield the requested results. A quick search about this dictionary presented this thread, which may be the solution. I'll try it out when I'm back at work: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/31060

Comment: @RicardPérezdelCampo If you post that comment as an answer, I'll accept it. I'm posting my working code based off the link I referenced in my original question, but I only got that with your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ricard answered this question in his comment, but here's the elaboration:

If you go into the Cocos2d folder under libs, you'll find `CSpriteFrameCache.h` and `CCSpriteFrameCache.m`.

Change your CCSpriteFrameCache.h file to include this additional line:

```
@interface CCSpriteFrameCache : NSObject
{
    ...(existing code)
    NSMutableDictionary *showSpriteFrames;//or whatever you want to call it
}
```

Then, in CCSpriteFrameCache.m, add this:

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *) showSpriteFrames 
{
    return spriteFrames_;
}
```

Then wherever in your code you want to have the sprite frames currently in your cache displayed, enter this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *framesDict = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] showSpriteFrames];

for (NSString *frameKey in framesDict)
{
    CCLOG(@"Frame name: %@", frameKey);
}
```

Answer attributed to this link: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/31060